# How do I copy substring to array of strings

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java, selenium-webdriver

```
WebElement ELR = driver.findElement(By.id("trades-list"));
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(
  By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'trade-summary-92')]")
);

String[] tradeId = null; 
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
{
    String str = list.get(i).getAttribute("id");
    tradeId[i] = str.substring(23);
    System.out.println(tradeId[i]);
}
```

str will contain following list is the output of `String str = list.get(i).getAttribute("id");`

> trade-summary-92222
>  
>   trade-summary-93333
>   trade-summary-94444

Here I want to print 92222, 93333, 94444 in the string tradeId.

I am getting the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: -4     at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.traderev.selenium.multipleBrowser.main(multipleBrowser.java:71)

Comment: Glad to have helped. If your question is solved, you should accept Niels' answer. It answers the original question of copying substrings very nicely.

Answer (score 3):

How do you come to 23 in `tradeId[i] = str.substring(23);`, your strings like trade-summary-92222 are only 19 characters long, not?

19 - 23 = -4, which is what your errors says its can't find the last 4 characters.

For readability and a partial string you could use: `public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

Your code would become:

```
tradeId[i] = str.substring(19-5, 19);
```

Or try just this to get the last five

```
tradeId[i] = str.substring(str.length() - 5);
```

Or to prevent the exception if the string becomes shorter then 5

```
tradeId[i] = str.substring(Math.max(0, text.length()-5));
```

Or this

```
tradeId[i] = str.substring(s.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```

Comment: I tried the above method but now getting exception as
Total count is3
trade-summary-92195
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.traderev.selenium.multipleBrowser.main(multipleBrowser.java:73)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a nullpointer exception because you're trying to assign values to index locations in a null array.

This statement

```
String[] tradeId = null;
```

should be

```
String[] tradeId = new String[list.size()];
```

so when you later do this:

```
tradeId[i] = str.substring(s.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```

There will be a space in the array reserved for that value.

Hope that helps!